# How to add object property in map

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to add property in map loop
But it seems I updated on a copy not the object itself.

```
MY_ARRAY.map(function(d){
  d.size = DO_SEOMTHING
});
```

Comment: post you arrays content as well.

Answer (score 2):

You have to reassign `MY_ARRAY`

```
MY_ARRAY = MY_ARRAY.map(function(d){
  d.size = [somevalue]; 
  return d; // as per comment
});
```

Another way to directly rewrite your array could be using the array itself as initial value (see MDN link for more on that):

```
MY_ARRAY.map(function(d, i){
  this[i].d.size = [somevalue];
}, MY_ARRAY);
```

From [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> The map() method creates a *new* array with the results of calling a
>   provided function on every element in this array.

Comment: Illegal usage of `.map()`..! Map's call back should return a value to create a new array based on the current one.

Comment: You're right @RajaprabhuAravindasamy. For the second variant it's not necesarry though.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) instead of using `.map`, `Map` will basically translate one array into another one array.

```
$.each(MY_ARRAY,function(i,d){
  d.size = DO_SEOMTHING
});
```